# Laravel Close mysql/mongodb connection

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

I am using **laravel 5.1** with **jenssengers** **mongodb**. I am unusre if the connection to the **mongodb** & **mysql** is closed when not in use.if not what is the way i can close the connection.

Comment: Why don't you put it in issues of github repo? It might help more.

Comment: Oh! I see what you're saying. Try to do fork and then change it accordingly, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the connections would be closed when not in use, you can use db.currentOp() to see whats running or hung up at the DB end.

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(
  function(op) {
    if(op.secs_running > 5) printjson(op);
  }
)
```

Reference - http://blog.mongolab.com/2014/02/mongodb-currentop-killop/

Comment: In mongo offcourse, use some tool like robomongo to run this